# Ffmpeg creating m3u8 from mp4, video file size

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, m3u8, bitrate

I am using ffmpeg to convert mp4 to m3u8. But first I need to make mp4 smaller. I use this code to make it smaller:

```
ffmpeg -i big.mp4 -b 1000000 small.mp4
```

Then I use this code to convert it to m3u8

```
ffmpeg -i small.mp4 -g 60 -hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_size 500000 output.m3u8
```

Is there a way to do this in once?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just combine them:

```
ffmpeg -i big.mp4 -b:v 1M -g 60 -hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_size 500000 output.m3u8
```

Note that you're transcoding the video *twice* in your current workflow. Since the 2nd command hasn't set video codec option to copy, it gets transcoded again - in CRF mode with value 23.