# How to assign variable to different extension of files in same directory in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ffmpeg

I have a task to:

1. Watch a folder for video files (mp4,mov,mkv etc.)
2. Transform the video files to HLS (480p, 720p, 1080p) using ffmpeg
3. Move these files to a different folder
4. Delete the original files from the watch folder
5. Send an email stating that the following video file was transcoded

I want to deal with every **.mp4** **.mov** and **.mkv** as a variable in bash so that I can perform the above-mentioned tasks.
The folder containing these files are in

```
/mnt/volume1/videos
```

directory architecture

```
/mnt/volum1/videos/sample.mp4
/mnt/volum1/videos/sample.mov
/mnt/volum1/videos/sample.mkv
```

Answer (score 1):

You can successively put every .mp4 .mov and .mkv file from your directory in a variable with a loop like that :

```
cd /mnt/volum1/videos/
for curFile in *.mp4 *.mov *.mkv ; do
    echo $curFile
done
```

you can remove the extension of the filename (everything that is after the last '.' 'of the filename) with the following variable substitution:

```
${curfile%.*}
```

I don't know about HLS, but here is a simple ffmpeg example:
If you call ffmpeg to make an avi file, it will look like:

```
ffmpeg -i $curfile ${curfile%.*}.avi
```

Comment: can you please share the command for ffmpeg to make m3u8 files?

Comment: I'm not familiar with m3u8, but this might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026691/ffmpeg-creating-m3u8-from-mp4-video-file-size